# Using awk to add a column between $4 and $5

Tags: parsing, awk, sed, multiple-columns

I am interested in being able to add an empty column with no values, that is an empty space followed by a tab into my csv file. I have working code with which I can add a column but I don't understand how to fill it with spaces followed by tab since I am attempting to insert it between two already existing columns `$4` and `$5` that span over 100k rows.

**My code**

```
cat file | NR==1 {print $0,"Ref"; next}
```

**Sample Input File**

```
Position        Food    Age     Occup   Loc     Avg
very stable     eggs    27      busy    out     100%
```

**Expected Output File**

```
Position        Food    Age     Occup   Ref     Loc     Avg
very stable     eggs    27      busy            out     100%
```

Simply, I am trying to create a column that is still tab-delimited over a span of ~100k rows. Thanks! I am aware that `sed` might work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$5=(NR>1 ? "" : "Ref") OFS $5} 1'
```

or if you REALLY want a blank char in the "Ref" column of the non-header lines for some reason:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$5=(NR>1 ? " " : "Ref") OFS $5} 1'
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
Position        Food    Age     Occup   Loc     Avg
very stable     eggs    27      busy    out     100%

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$5=(NR>1 ? "" : "Ref") OFS $5} 1' file
Position        Food    Age     Occup   Ref     Loc     Avg
very stable     eggs    27      busy            out     100%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,"Ref",$5,$6; next} 
{print $1,$2,$3,$4,"*",$5,$6}' file | column -t | tr "*" " "
```

**NOTE**

I'm assuming that `*` doesn't appear in file.